# Define object and pass by reference inside function parameter

Tags: c++

Lets say we have a function called `foo` that gets a pointer to some object.

```
void foo(int *i){
    // Some code
}
```

We can call this function the following way:

```
int i;
foo(&i);
```

Is there a way we can make the above snippet in one line in c++? Something like

```
foo(&int(4)) // This is invalid.
```

Two limitations:

1. Changing `foo` to receive by-reference is not an option.
2. We also want to avoid using something like `foo(new int(4))` which can lead to memory leaks.

Comment: why  would you want something like `foo(&int(4))` ? Its not only invlalid by the rules of the language, but it just doesnt make much sense for `int*` argument. If `foo` is broken and takes the wrong type of argument you can write a wrapper for it

Comment: what is `foo` ? Why do you not need the pointee after the call?

Comment: No, you can't use rvalue (temporary int) with "addr of" operator. The signature of your function `void foo(int*)` suggests that it is possible to modify the `i`, so also semantically that wouldn't make any sense to pass the temporary.

Comment: `foo` is a library function that expects a pointer, I cannot modify it. But I also don't care whether `i` is modified or not. I know `foo(&int(4))` is invalid, as stated in the question, I am just asking if it's possible to create an object **and** pass it's address, all in one line (similar to _something_ like `foo(&int(4))`).

Comment: "possible to create an object and pass it's address" - No. To get the address, it needs to be lvalue (needs to have a name, not being a temporary). If the author of the lib designed it like this, then that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Doing all in one line" is usually not something desirable, because it does not make code more clean or more readable. If you have to declare an `int` and take its address, your code better expresses that explicitly.

However, the usual way to encapsulate common tasks is functions:

```
 void foo_wrapper() {
       int i = 0;
       foo(&i);
 }
```

Then call `foo_wrapper()` rather than `foo(&i)`.

PS: The elephant in the room is: `foo` apparently uses the argument as out-parameter, but you want to ignore it. If this is really how `foo` is supposed to be used, then it does unnecessary work. Writing the wrapper is hiding a flaw. To fix the actual issue `foo` would have to be modified. I know you said it is third party library code, but rather than writing workarounds for library code, I would reconsider if (a) it is the right library or (b) perhaps I do misunderstand how it is supposed to be used.

PPS: I assumed that passing `nullptr` is not an option. If passing a `nullptr` is an option then simply do that.

Comment: Since we don't care what happens to `i`, what are some advantages (if any) of using this instead of passing `NULL` as @Agent_L suggests in his answer?

Comment: @AristotelisV `foo` might expect a non-nullptr. If `foo` is fine with passing a nullptr then its fine :), though then the question is moot in the first place

Comment: @AristotelisV you are asking how to declare an `int` and get a pointer to it in a single line of code. If you are fine with passing a `nullptr` to `foo`, then you dont need an `int`

Comment: @AristotelisV If the function cannot handle `NULL` it means it wasn't intended to be used without parameter. So you might be doing something against the design or the function breaks single-responsibility principle and should be refactored. IF this is `strncpy`-like function and you're ignoring or hardcoding the buffer/affected size it could mean you're opening your code for a dangerous buffer overrun. Investigate WHY this parameter is mandatory and make it optional if there is no reason.

Comment: The classic case for unwanted outputs is by-products.  Not all code needs all the outputs produced by a given algorithm. It's friendly to accept `nullptr` but in hard optimised code it might be better to demand non-null inputs. The classic textbook case is remainder after division but other examples are output functions that provide a count of characters printed that isn't required in the case in hand or instrumentation that isn't always being used.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why such behaviour would be required and assume it's some kind of 'Brain Teaser' question.
If it's an exercise in "macro magic" there may be better solutions.

This is valid:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void f(int *x){
    ++(*x);
    std::cout << *x << '\n';
}
int main() {
     f(std::make_unique<int>(4).get()); 
    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output: `5`

The temporary object (of type `std::unique<int>`) will be cleaned up after the function call. No memory leaked but there is of course overhead in dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1):

`&` and `std::addressof` are explicitly specified to disallow this, but if you want to ignore that safety measure, you can define your own wrapper around `std::addressof` that will allow it:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto myaddressof(T&& t) noexcept {
    return std::addressof(t);
}

//...

// temporary created from argument to `addressof` lives
// until end of full-expression
foo(myaddressof(4));
```

That's quite easy to get wrong though. For example if you replace `T&&` with `T`, then using it may result in undefined behavior. This relies on rules for temporary lifetime that are probably not intuitive. I don't really think this is better style than declaring a variable and wrapping it with the call in a block.

Full demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/qjbKnYPMP) based on a comment by @JasonLiam.

(Note that you probably shouldn't use `addressof` as name for this function. There are some corner cases where argument-dependent lookup will cause problems with that name if called unqualified.)

Comment: Put the function call inside `main` or some other function instead of global namespace. You can add this [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fa3EvEM1v)

Comment: @JasonLiam It is not supposed to be complete code, hence the `//...`, but I added the link to your demo (with a minor adjustment).

Answer (score 1):

`void foo(int *i)` expresses intent that the lifetime of the argument is managed by the caller, outside of `foo`. Which means allocating some time before `foo` call and deallocating some time after `foo` returns. So one liner is out of the question because of your reason #2.

The idiomatic way of handling optional pointer values is to use `nullptr` or `NULL` (pre-C++11) argument as an indicator to ignore it: `foo(nullptr)`.

Comment: The more idiomatic way would be to use `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrapper class (which in a way is similar to the other answer with `myaddressof` function template):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class my_wrapper_class
{
  public:
    my_wrapper_class(T const &v) : value(v)
    {
    }
    T *operator&()
    {
      return(&value);
    }
    T const *operator&() const
    {
      return(&value);
    }
  private:
    T value;
};

void f(int *v)
{
  std::cout << "v: " << *v << std::endl;
  (*v)++;
}

int main()
{
  f(&my_wrapper_class<int>(4));
  return(0);
}
```

Please note that EVERY book about C++ I've read strongly advises against overloading unary operator `&` which I've just did. The other option (not shown) is to define conversion operator to appropriate pointer and omission of explicit `&` at call site which in my opinion is equally confusing.

Putting it here so it is available for those in need with a strong disclaimer - DON'T DO THAT. Consider what others wrote on this topic before heading this way.